# libobjc: Calling a ObjC method from plain C?

Tags: objective-c, libobjc

I am currently experimenting with the [V programming language](https://github.com/vlang/v) and looked at a few fun things I wanted to try out. One of the things that I wondered was, if I could call Objective-C methods from plain C without compiling a single `.m` file.

Since Python can do it with pyobjc, I wonder if I could make it work in V?

Imagine the following, very crude code:

```
@implementation Foo

- (id) greet: (char*)me {
  printf("Hello %s!", me);
}

@end
```

Now, I know that with `objc_sendMsg` I can send messages - but how do I create the proper instance first?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to look something like this:

```
Class fooClass = objc_lookUpClass("Foo");
id obj = class_createInstance(fooClass, 0);
SEL initSelector = sel_registerName("init");
((id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(obj,initSelector);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a little easier than I thought. What is the second argument to `class_createInstance` for exactly?

Comment: [class_createInstance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1441565-class_createinstance/) It is a count of extra bytes you want allocated to the object instance.  You could use them to hide instance data that is not expressed in the public `@interface` structure declaration.  Seems to me like something best to avoid that unless you have very specialized needs.